# Nivo Slider на весь экран

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать, что бы Nivo Slider отображал картинки на весь экран для любого разрешения?
На текущий момент при загрузке страницы изображение растягивается на весь экран, как и надо. Но когда срабатывает первое переключене слайда, то смена происходит по границе самого изображения(например 670px, то есть на эране уже становится две картинки).
Для слайдера и картинок прописал:

```css
.nivoSlider {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.nivoSlider img {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Но не помогает. Есть у кого идеи на этот счет?

Comment: дайте пример кода, одного css недостаточно.